# hclust, R and Euclidean distances: weird stuff

Tags: r, clustering, distance-functions

I have a table of similarities expressed through cosines and am trying to do some cluster analysis in R, using `hclust` and `method=ward`.

First I need to turn cosines into squared Euclidean distances, knowing that $d=2(1-\cos)$. No problem. I turned `myData` into `myDataDist`.

But then when I use `hclust (myDataDist, method=ward)` it gives me an error:

```
must have n >= 2 objects to cluster
```

The craziest thing is that if I turn the table of cosines into Euclidean distances with the `dist` function: `myDataDist <- dist(myData, method = "euclidean")` it works just fine, but then the dendrogram plotted by `hclust` is wrong. (I know because I tried with another clustering program.)

Has anybody checked the code of `dist` or `ward` methods in R? Why doesn't `hclust` work as it should, with Euclidean squared distances computed manually as $d=2(1-\cos)$?

Comment: The error is likely at your side. Did you read the documentation of hclust? It says about the arguments `d a dissimilarity structure as produced by dist`. Also how do you know the dendrogramm is wrong?

Comment: hum.I am not quite sure about this. I read the documentation, yes, of course. That's the point. The function dist produces a dissimilarity structure that looks different from the one you would get by computing the squared euclidean distances manually, with the geometric formula d=2(1−cos). (you need euclidean squared distances in order to apply the ward method to a hierarchical clustering).   Also, I believe that it is wrong because I plotted the same data with Multidendrograms (another program that works with cosines as well as with distances) and it comes out a different graph.

Comment: Does it work with other methods than ward?

Comment: yes it does, there is complete linkage, single linkage etc, I haven't checked which distance metrics they need, in any case but I need the Ward method

Comment: @mariannabol Your example is not reproducible but likely (and why I pointed you to the documentation) your $d$ is not an object that hclust recognizes (as it is not of class dist). Also, if you have a result you are happy with from Multidendrogramm, why do you need another one?

Comment: hi Anony-Mousse. I'dneed another program, that can give also some tools for cluster validation (internal purity of the cluster solution, etc, something like that) and Muldidendrograms does not have what I ' d need in terms of validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not given a lot of information. Two things to check are this. First, `dist` uses the *rows* of a matrix as units, not the columns (as is more customary in R analyses). Second, if you produce your own distance you have to pass it to hclust as `as.dist(myDataDist)`.